# Objective-C: Compiler warning for accidental method override

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I just found a bug in our iOS App which was triggered by an accidental method override.

In this case a property in a Subclass override a "private" method in the Superclass.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)doSomething {
    [self hideView];
}
- (void)hideView {
}
@end

@interface MySubclass : MyClass
@property (NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) IBInspectable BOOL hideView;
@end

@implementation MySubclass
@end
```

If `[self hideView]` is called within the `doSomething` method, the `hideView` method is not called. Instead just the property is asked for its value. I understand why this is happening but this is a error prone situation since the subclass is not aware of the `hideView` method.

My question is how to prevent those issues? Is there a compiler warning?

Comment: The compiler cannot know about the existence of `hideView` when it's private. The only reference to hidden method are in the object files (frameworks / libs) which the compiler cannot access.

Comment: I see, why this is not possible. The static analyzer could possibly to that. Since the types don't match this is definitely an error case. I guess I'm going to file an radar

Comment: The static analyzer is based on the compiler, too. It has also no access to the object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not completely prevent those issues, this is the intended behaviour in Objective C. However, if you want to protect your private methods from accidental override, you can prefix their names with an identifier of your library (or any other string that you like), for example:

```
- (void)__mylib_hideView {}
```